# Compiling + executing in runtime Java Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins

We're trying to write an INTELLIJ IDEA plugin, but this question is not about the plugin itself. We're trying to compile and execute a given code from the plugin.
We're using `generalCommandLine` which gets parameters in the same way as Terminal.

We tried various of parameters but never succeeded.

Here is our code:

```java
public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent event) {
        ArrayList<String> cmds = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> cmds2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        cmds.add("javac"); // for compilation
        cmds.add("com/test/Main.java"); // path for java file to compile
        cmds2.add("java"); // for execution
        cmds2.add("com.test.Main"); // package which the compiled file is in (Main.class)
        GeneralCommandLine generalCommandLine = new GeneralCommandLine(cmds);
        GeneralCommandLine generalCommandLine1 = new GeneralCommandLine(cmds2);
        generalCommandLine1.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        generalCommandLine1.setWorkDirectory("/home/tout/IdeaProjects/test/src");
        generalCommandLine.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        generalCommandLine.setWorkDirectory("/home/tout/IdeaProjects/test/src");

        System.out.println(generalCommandLine.getWorkDirectory());
        try {
            ProcessHandler processHandler = new OSProcessHandler(generalCommandLine);
            processHandler.startNotify();
            System.out.println("test1");
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            ProcessHandler processHandler1 = new OSProcessHandler(generalCommandLine1);
            processHandler1.startNotify();
            System.out.println("test2");
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

`generalCommandLine` actually compiles the code into `.class`, but `generalCommandLine1` doesn't execute the code - the code is just a project we created in Intellij which creates a file and writes into it.
(the code which creates a file and writes to it is fine because once we run it in IntelliJ - everything works.)

What are we missing here?

Comment: Can you see any stdout/stderr messages at all from the `process1Handler.startNotify()`? There is no stack trace logged in your catch block? Your Main.java class does have a Main method? Can you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: I can't see any messages.. my Main..java has a Main Method..